# Function that runs forever

Tags: python, performance, time, jupyter-notebook

I have a homework problem where I have to combine several functions to return certain output involving kmeans clustering.

Instead of using sklearn's kmeans module, we are required to combine some pre-written functions that replicate what's "under the hood" of the kmeans module with our own cosine similarity distance calculator.  I was able to find code to help put together the cosine similarity calculator ('cosine_sim'), and then the instructor gave us the code that performs the kmeans clustering ('randCent' and 'kmeans').  All three functions are below.

In order to write the function that uses these outputs, I've tried running this kmeans functions to see the shape/type of outputs it creates.  However, it seems to run forever.  This isn't that surprising, considering my training data has 2,000 rows and the there are 9,328 columns (word frequencies).  I let it run for 9-10 hours overnight and this morning it was still running.  I tried making a smaller training set--even one with only 5 rows, and it still runs forever.  I've also tried it on a different computer but same result.

Is there a problem in the code (such as being stuck in a loop) or is it something that will just have to take several days to run fully?

TIA for any help.

```
## Import Modules
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd
from os import chdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

## Cosine distance calculation function (that I found elsewhere)

def cosine_sim (vec1, vec2):
    x_sqr_sum = 0 
    y_sqr_sum = 0
    xy_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(vec1)):
        x = vec1[i] 
        y = vec2[i]
        x_sqr_sum += x*x
        y_sqr_sum += y*y
        xy_sum += x*y
    return xy_sum/sqrt(x_sqr_sum*y_sqr_sum)

##  Function that creates centroids (provided by instructor)

def randCent(dataSet, k):
    n = shape(dataSet)[1]
    centroids = zeros((k,n), dtype=float)
    for j in range(n): #create random cluster centers
        minJ = min(dataSet[:,j])
        rangeJ = float(max(dataSet[:,j]) - minJ)
        centroids[:,j] = minJ + rangeJ * random.rand(k)
    return centroids 

##  Function that performs kMeans clustering (provided by instructor and calls the previous two functions

def kMeans(dataSet, k, distMeas=cosine_sim, createCent=randCent):
    m = shape(dataSet)[0]
    clusterAssment = zeros((m,2))#create mat to assign data points 
                                      #to a centroid, also holds SE of each point
    centroids = createCent(dataSet, k)
    clusterChanged = True
    while clusterChanged:
        clusterChanged = False
        for i in range(m):#for each data point assign it to the closest centroid
            minDist = inf; minIndex = -1
            for j in range(k):
                distJI = distMeas(centroids[j,:],dataSet[i,:])
                if distJI < minDist:
                    minDist = distJI; minIndex = j
            if clusterAssment[i,0] != minIndex: clusterChanged = True
            clusterAssment[i,:] = minIndex,minDist**2
        #print (centroids)
        for cent in range(k):#recalculate centroids
            ptsInClust = dataSet[nonzero(clusterAssment[:,0]==cent)[0]] #get all the point in this cluster - Note: this was incorrect in the original distribution.
            if(len(ptsInClust)!=0):
                centroids[cent,:] = mean(ptsInClust, axis=0)
    return centroids, clusterAssment
```

Comment: The only place that looks obvious is `if clusterAssment[i,0] != minIndex: clusterChanged = True` - are you certain that `clusterAssment` will eventually/ever be equal to `minIndex`? Also, when you run `clusterAssment[i,:] = minIndex,minDist**2`, does that change `clusterAssment[i,0]`? If not, it'll run forever, since it's never changed.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that was the problem.  I altered the while loop so that it would only run 100 iterations.

Comment: Keep us posted if that solves the question!

Comment: Sorry, not only am I a programming noob, but I'm still somewhat of a noob on this site and I want to make sure I follow the rules/make things as helpful as possible.  

What do I need to do if the altered while loop works?  Do I make changes to my original post?

Comment: If it works, let me know, and I'll post my comment as an answer. That answer can then be accepted, and future users will know what works.